# Using PCA to project onto a lower dimensional space in Octave

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, octave, pca, dimensionality-reduction

I have the following matrix of size 300 x 2, which contains min-max normalised data:

```
# Pre-Process data
scaled_acc = preprocess(mtx_accuracy);

# PCA on mtx_accuracy
[pcvars pcvecs] = princomp(scaled_acc);
```

`preprocess` is a scaling function:

```
function zScore = preprocess(data)
    means = ones(length(data),1);
    means = means * mean(data);
    stds = ones(length(data),1);
    stds = stds * std(data);
    zScore = (data - means) ./ stds;
endfunction
```

How can I reduce (to 1 dimension) and project the data, so that I have a single column vector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second output variable `pcvecs` already contains your projected data in `n` dimensions where `n` is the total number of columns in your data matrix.  As such, if you want to see your data projected onto a subset of `m` dimensions where `m < n`, you just have to extract out the first `m` columns of `pcvecs`.

In your case, `m=1`, and as such it would just be:

```
reduced = pcvecs(:,1);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, I sort of figured that bit out. I am trying to derive my new dataset, which I am guessing is done by transposing the scaled matrix and multiplying it with the reduced vector?

Comment: @Alex - Correct.  To do a full reconstruction, it's simply: `pcavecs*pcvars.'`.  However, this does a full reconstruction with all of the dimensions intact.  If you want to do a reconstruction with a reduced number of dimensions, you would do: `pcavecs(:,1:m)*pcvars(:,1:m).'` where `m` is the number of reduced dimensions... but this is **uncentered**.  You need to remember what the means of each variable is so you can add these back to the uncentered data.

Comment: Yes, thank you so much, this is what I've been looking! Dare I ask, what do you mean by uncentered (a link would suffice)?

Comment: @Alex - Just edited my comment.  `princomp` **uncenters** your data by default - which means that the mean of each feature in your data matrix is subtracted away from the data.  As such, if you want to do a reconstruction, once you do the multiplication I linked to you above, you must **readd** the means of each feature back onto the reconstruction.  However, because you are already removing the mean, this step isn't necessary.  As such, simply doing the multiplication that I linked to you above is sufficient.  You're very welcome btw :) Good luck!

Comment: Great, I won't need reconstruction, so this is exactly what I needed, thanks a bunch!